# Foundation Sites (6) javascript order

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am utterly confused as how to insert individual foundation javascript.  it always seem to break my code.  for example I need to use the dropdown menu js. in the documentation it state

> Initializing
>   The file foundation.dropdownMenu.js must be included in your JavaScript to use this plugin,
>
> along with foundation.core.js.
>
> This plugin also requires these utility libraries:
>
> foundation.util.keyboard.js
>
> foundation.util.box.js
>
> foundation.util.nest.js

this seem simple enough so I did the following in this order

```
bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.core.js  //check 
bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.mediaQuery.js
bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.timerAndImageLoader.js
bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.keyboard.js  //check 
bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.box.js  //check 
bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.util.nest.js  //check 
bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.dropdown.js
bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.dropdownMenu.js  //check 
bower_components/foundation-sites/js/foundation.equalizer.js
```

I follow what logical for me core 1st than util than plugin
yet it told me `foundation.util.nest.js:6 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =`

if I put all foundation.min.js file the error go away, so I know it must be a dependency is missing or the order is not correct

is there any resource out there that is clear on the dependency of foundation js? instead everytime I have to trail and error it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Foundation v6.2.0 the JavaScript codebase has been updated to ES6.
https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/releases

You'll need to add Babel to your build process to compile the ES6 code.

They have supplied a tutorial for this here:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/wiki/Upgrading-to-Foundation-6.2

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue on my end. I am using Foundation as a GIT subtree in my project and actually have used this on a site I made just last week.

It seems that the problem is a newer version of function parameter declarations. In the code I had working, v6.1.2, the code in foundation.util.nest.js is:

```
Foundation.Nest = {
  Feather: function(menu, type){
    menu.attr('role', 'menubar');
    type = type || 'zf';
```

versus the code in the newest version 6.2.0 which is:

```
const Nest = {
  Feather(menu, type = 'zf') {
    menu.attr('role', 'menubar');
```

It's that default/fallback declaration of "type" that seems to ruin everything. I look forward to a fix myself.

According to [this link](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), my current version of Chrome (48) doesn't yet support default function parameters.

Comment: Thanks. Let me know if you come up with anything.

Comment: I actually edited the code which I don't typically like to do so it mirrors what is there for the 6.1.2. I'll try to watch the repo to see if Zend pushes a change which fixes this issue.